# Why are my sections are overlapping, no bg-color? CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is my code.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwoLdR

The text of my sections are overlapping, and the `background-color: #xxxxxx;` of every section is not showing up.

This may be a **position** issue, but when I change `position: relative;` to `absolute`, the text aligns to the left even though it is set as center.

This may also be a **height** issue, because in the browser the dimensions sometimes show up  as "880px x 0px".

Comment: Always post your code in your question please. Examples on sites like codepen, jsFiddle, jsbin, etc. should supplement the code in your question, not be the sole source of it.

Comment: it works perfectly when not in codepen, i just moved it into its on html file and here is the result - http://postimg.org/image/jovumgb3p/

Comment: If you remove the `min-` from the `min-height` in the CSS for `body`, the codepen works too.

Comment: @MatthewHammond that's interesting because when the exact html/css code is in my Ruby on Rails app, the overlapping problem (like on codepen) exists. but when the code is in normal html/css files, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Serendipity How weird! It might be when you export it, it add random pointless code which is corrupting it, I know adobe muse adds extra code, but I'm not sure about ruby on rail. Sorry I can't help with that.

Comment: THAT WAS IT! thank you Mister @MrLister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the line-height of the h2 in your css, as well as the "strong" tag to fix the overlap, and give your "section" tags a static height. The problem with percentage based heights is if the parent container (in this case the body) has no specified height, the children will have a height of 60% of 0 which is 0. Thats why the content wasnt visible.

```
.second strong {
  color: #32B432;
  line-height:40px;
}

h2 {
  line-height:24px;
}
```

[here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbgoKo) is a working example

An even easier way would be to use

```
body {
  height:100%;
}
```

rather than

```
body {
  min-height:100%;
}
```

if you dont mind a static body. [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJwYNX) is an example of that.

Comment: The quote "...a wealth of information creates a poverty of attention..." - Herbert Simon (1971)
still isnt shown

Comment: @Serendipity OK, I edited the answer, and the link. Everything is working now :)